# Restrict access/media resources request from a specific domain solution, instead of direct access by .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to make a domain, for example, `media.mywebpage.com` to store media access.

Then, I hope to restrict direct access and other domains haven't whitelist. That's mean people cannot directly type `media.mywebpage.com/img/foo.png` in their browser, then it will return 403.

But whitelist a domain, for example, `blog.mywebpage.com`. Allow all requests from this domain, then return right media access to the web page (status 200).

Please note that `media.mywebpage.com` is a media library, I hope to modify .htaccess from the root directory of this domain.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a routing script is used to access such resources. Either by direct link or by means of rewriting incoming requests to that routing script. That script obviously allows you to perform whatever authorization check you want. And yes, that means that the actual media resources should *not* be part of the file system section published by the http server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?img/ /path/to/script.php [END]
```

THen `script.php` (not necessarily a php script, obviously) can perform the authorization check, for example by testing the referrer domain (keep in mind though that such check is very easy to spoof, since the referrer header is easy to spoof). For example you can evaluate the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` superglobal variable in php. Or whatever you want. If the authorization is granted, then the script reads and hands out the media resource as response to the request, if not it returns an 401 header. The advantage of such approach is that you are flexible in what the script actually should do, especially for later extensions like user based sessions or whatever.

An alternative is to directly implement this on the level of the http server, but as said that is limited:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^blog\.mywebpage\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=401]
```

Both approaches are not exactly robust, no not reliable. Trying to prevent hot linking that way sometimes works, sometimes not. Question is why you want to deny access to a resource anyway, considering you explicitly published it...